# In a form in rails, show the options according to what was chosen in the first question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a report form, the first line show all the clients, I need when i chose one client, the second line show only the offices of that client and no all the offices of all the clients.

```
<%= form.select :client_id, collection: Client.all.map { |r| [r.name, r.id] } %>
<%= form.select :office_id, collection: Office.all.map { |r| [r.name, r.id] } %>
```

```rb
# Client
has_many :offices
```

```rb
# Office
belongs_to :client
has_many :reports
```

Comment: This is a very common and extremely broad question - not just in Rails but in web development in general. You could either do this by creating a grouped select if you have a relatively limited number of questions. Or you would need to attach an event handler to the first element which then gets the offices per country with an ajax request from your Rails application. Its not actually answerable as that would take an entire book or a very very long tutorial.

Comment: There is also no shortage of gems, javascript libraries and jQuery monstrosities that aim to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need a nested select or nested dropdown, can be solved in many ways. There's already a answer for your question  [How to implement Nested Dropdowns in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750250/how-to-implement-nested-dropdowns-in-rails)